# How To detect swipe starting and ending position not touch event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, jqtouch, swipe

```
jQuery("#surface").bind("mousedown", function(e)
{
     console.log("(x,y) = (" + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY +")"); 
});
```

I wrote this code but not track that it is touch event or swipe event.I want to call function which fired when swipe event start and end.When you touch a finger on iPad/iPhone and push and drag to left or right.I want finger touching starting position (x,y) cordinate and need (x,y) position when you drop a finger.

I also used jqTouch but it don't give me starting and ending position.

I want to make App which swipe page according to your finger.

------------ HTML  ------------

```
<canvas id="surface">
     //  here goes all image pages 
</canvas>
```

do you have any idea about how to detect swipe start and end event using jQuery or javascript but not touch event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe)?

Also, if that's not feasible, what you're gonna need to do is set a timer on touchstart and touchend

FYI, I know jQuery plug site is broke, but you can find the download for [that plugin here](http://www.ryanscherf.net/demos/swipe/jquery.jswipe.js)